# Different IP from Android device (3G) and whatismyip.com?

Tags: android, networking

Why do I get a different ip using:

[Getting the IP address of the android device when connected to 3G mobile network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818725/getting-the-ip-address-of-the-android-device-when-connected-to-3g-mobile-network)

That I do by going to whatismyip.com and is there a way to get the "real ip".

The difference that I have seen between the two ips is that sending UDP packages to the whatismyip.com ip get through much faster than the ip provided by android.

I also saw in logcat that the ip address that whatismyip.com is being found by someother service:

I/pppd    ( 3178): local  IP address 107.52.xxx.xxx
I/pppd    ( 3178): remote IP address 66.1.xxx.xxx

So there must be a way... or some other service is getting the ip from some web service

Answer (score 3):

Probably your ISP [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) your connection, so with whatismyip.com you see the public IP, with that Android code you see the private (local) IP