# How can we find out what IP is being assigned to an iphone or android on 3G or gsm network using titanium?

Tags: android, ios, titanium-mobile

How can we find out what IP is being assigned to an iphone or android when its connected on  3G or gsm network using titanium?

Comment: For Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818725/getting-the-ip-address-of-the-android-device-when-connected-to-3g-mobile-network

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to get IP address (except Wi-Fi) by using Titanium API, but if your application involves a server, then you can get the ip address using the server variables, as the ip will always be received at server along with other header data.

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)  for fetching at server.