# Android IP address

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I am new to android development and socket programming.I am trying to connect two mobiles on different networks using sockets. I was able to connect two devices on same network or LAN. I would like to ask two things.
1. How can two devices can communicated lets say one on 3G and other using WIFI.
2. What is this string fe90::c762:7acc:a801:dc87%wlan. The following link has the code which retruns two things one the above string and another 192.168.1.5 like an ip adress. I am not sure what that string is. Can someone please explain? thanks!!

[Code that returns that string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818725/getting-the-ip-address-of-the-android-device-when-connected-to-3g-mobile-network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to connect two mobiles on different networks using sockets

Generally, that will not be possible.

> How can two devices can communicated lets say one on 3G and other using WIFI

Generally, that will not be possible. Most WiFi networks issue private IP addresses; most mobile carriers issue private IP addresses. You would need one or both of them to be public IP addresses to directly communicate with each other. This is a standard P2P communications problem and has nothing specifically to do with Android --  you will run into the same problem connecting two desktops on different networks.

> What is this string fe90::c762:7acc:a801:dc87%wlan

That is [an IPv6 address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address) with a [zone index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Link-local_addresses_and_zone_indices).

Comment: Hmm.. Thats exactly what I want. P2P communication. Like you said most of Wifi networks and mobile carriers issues private IP then how P2P is possible?

Comment: @user3787605: Literal P2P may not be possible between two devices on separate mobile networks. I would assume that you will need some intermediate server that can be reached by both sides. I suggest searching `android p2p library` on your favorite search engine.

Comment: Design of my app is, I'll have a server and each device will be connected to the server whenever it'll be connected to internet. And if device A wants to communicate device B then A will gets B's ip address from the server and then connection establish phase and then p2p communication starts. But you are saying it isn't possible.Right?

Comment: @user3787605: "But you are saying it isn't possible.Right?" -- correct.

Comment: lol sorry that am asking stupid question. One last question. I am developing an IM for android and I want p2p communication. What will you suggest? How is this possible? Any library or anything?

Comment: @user3787605: Many IM solutions use XMPP servers, and there are XMPP libraries for Android, such as aSmack.